# Differential equation defined from curve geometrical property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve a given DE (of a hyperbola):

$$(x-\frac{y}{y'})( y-{x}{y'})= 4c^2 \tag 1$$

in a roundabout way since after multiplication ( putting $y'=p)$ in

$$ p^2x^2 + 2p (2 c^2-xy) +y^2=0 \tag 2  $$

it appears to have no further advantage towards solution.

Chain Rule on differentiation

$$ \dfrac{-(x-\dfrac{y}{p})}{(y-{x}{p})}=\dfrac{1- \dfrac{y^{'2}-y y^{''}}{y^{'2}}}{y'-(y'+xy^{''})}= \dfrac{-y}{xp^2}  \tag 3 $$

Cross multiply to simplify gives

$$ p^2 =\frac{y^2}{x^2}  \tag4$$

Integration of first factor $$ p= \frac{y}{x} \tag5 $$

leads to  $$ y = C_1 x \tag6 $$

and, integration of second factor

$$ p= -\frac{y}{x} \tag7 $$

leads to  $$ xy = C_2 \tag8 $$

The latter is in fact $$ xy = c^2, same \, c $$

due to the property of hyperbola whose intercepts on the coordinate axes have a product $4c^2.$

The graph given below also verifies it geometrically alongwith individual terms that the product of sum of two axal segments on either axis is

$$ OX \cdot OY = c^2, OP \cdot OQ = (OX+XP)(OY+YQ) =(x-\frac{y}{y'})( y-{x}{y'})= 4c^2 \tag9  $$

in the case of curve now identified as hyperbola after integration.

It is also seen that the tangent segment in the first quadrant is bisected at $(x,y)$ as another property.

What is an easier way to solve this question?

How can  5) be discarded whereas 7) adopted except by the hindsight got by this calculation?

( Link since [deleted by OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575252/differential-equation-for-tangent-problem), *however,* please note my question is quite separate and different. I had calculated it before its deletion)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the (repeated ! ) typo error. Other work remains unaffected.Request change in your comments after my typo correction.

Comment: OK. I deleted my first comment. The corrected equation is a Lagrange's kind of ODE : $$y=x\,p\pm 2c\sqrt{-p}$$ To solve it : https://www.math24.net/lagrange-clairaut-equations/

Comment: Why did my elimination of given constant $c$ go off so totally astray?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot say. They are not enough steps to check.

Comment: Step (3) is Chain rule. If product $ u v =$ const, then $ \dfrac{-u}{v}=\dfrac{u'}{v'} $ which are differentiated and simplified Constants of given DE should not be diluted as they are geometrical properties.. right? That might be my error. I would value your comment.

Comment: This is not valid if $v=0$. So, Eq.(3) is valid if $y-xp\neq 0$ , hence Eq.(5) is not valid. To avoid the trouble,  instead of $\frac{-u}{v}=\frac{u'}{v'}$ , use $uv'+vu'=0$ . After simplification, $y''$ comes into factor. So the solutions issued from $y''=0$ are not forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x-\frac{y}{y'})( y-\frac{x}{y'})= 4c^2 \tag 1$$
The solution appears complicated, probably requiring special functions.

Probably there is a typo in $(1)$.

I guess that the equation is :
$$(x-\frac{y}{y'})( y-xy')= 4c^2 \tag 2$$
which general solution is a set of straight lines :$\quad y=-\frac{a^2}{4c^2}x+a \quad$ (with arbitrary constant $a$), without forgetting the particular solution : $\quad y=\frac{c^2}{x}\quad$ which is the hyperbola envelop of the set of straight lines.

In addition :

ANALYTICAL SOLVING of $\quad(x-\frac{y}{y'})( y-xy')= 4c^2$

$(xy'-y)( y-xy')= 4c^2y' \quad\to\quad (xy'-y)^2=-4c^2y'\quad\implies\quad y'\leq 0$

$(xy'-y)=\pm 2c\sqrt{-y'} \quad\to\quad y=xy'\mp 2c\sqrt{-y'}$

$y'=\left(xy'\mp 2c\sqrt{-y'} \right)'= y'+xy''\pm \frac{cy''}{\sqrt{-y'}}$

$$y''\left(x\pm \frac{c}{\sqrt{-y'}}\right)=0 \quad\to\quad \begin{cases}
y''=0 \\
x\pm \frac{c}{\sqrt{-y'}}=0
\end{cases}$$

PARTICULAR SOLUTION : From $\quad x\pm \frac{c}{\sqrt{-y'}}=0$

$\pm\sqrt{-y'}=\frac{c}{x}\quad\to\quad y'=-\frac{c^2}{x^2} \quad\to\quad y=\frac{c^2}{x}+$constant.

Putting it back into equation $(2)$ shows that the constant $=0$.
$$y=\frac{c^2}{x} \tag 3$$

GENERAL SOLUTION : From $\quad y''=0  \quad\to\quad y=a+bx$

Putting it back into equation $(2)$ leads to

$(x-\frac{a+bx}{b})( (a+bx)-xb)= 4c^2\quad\to\quad -\frac{a^2}{b}=4c^2\quad\to\quad b=-\frac{a^2}{4c^2}$
$$y=-\frac{a^2}{4c^2}x+a \tag 4$$
With arbitrary constant $a$.

The general solution is the set of straight lines $(4)$ and its curve envelop $(3)$ which is the hyperbola.

Comment: Ok, the typo is corrected.